# How to overwrite existing file during file download rather than create a new file

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT to do file upload, question, how to just overwrite existing file if exists rather create a new file, ex, file(1).doc. Here is my server side code.

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            String modelPath = AutoConstants.PREFIX + "/var/models/";

            File file = new File(modelPath + "/" + MODEL_NAME);

            if (file.exists()) {

                ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                        file));

                response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                        "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                response.setHeader("Content-Length",
                        String.valueOf(file.length()));
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; fileName=\"" + MODEL_NAME + "\"");

                int i = 0;
                int BUFSIZE = 8192;
                byte[] bbuf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
                while ((in != null) && ((i = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                    out.write(bbuf, 0, i);
                }

                in.close();
                out.flush();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception.getModel", e);
            throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a file download, not a file upload. The browser, or the user of the browser, decides what to do with the file. It's not under your control.

Comment: @JBNizet MY bad, I meant file download. So it depends on the browser whether to overwrite/create a new file during file downloading?

Comment: It will never overwrite without asking the user first. That would be a horrible feature: any web site could guess what a user has in its downloads folder, and trick the user into downloading an unknown file that would overwrite the file that the user doesn't want to lose.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, get it. Can you tell me how to overwrite if there is a requirement?

Comment: Again, it's not under your control. Tell the guy writing these requirements that this one can't be achieved.